# Angular - changing color and text of a div on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the color of a div on click of `ng-click`. I could make it work by changing the color, but now I need to change the text of the div when the same is clicked, so per example, I need change the color and replace the text inside per the one: clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!

    <div ng-init="item.isyellow = false" ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-class="{yellow : $index == row}"  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-click="colorRow($index)"  style="cursor:pointer"  >
        {{item.id}}
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.realName=[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"},{"id":3,"name":"c"},{"id":4,"name":"D"},{"id":5,"name":"E"},{"id":6,"name":"F"}];

    $scope.colorRow = function(index){
        $scope.row = index;
    }    

}
```

**CSS:**

```
.odd{
    background-color:white;  
}
.even{  
     background-color:grey;
}
.yellow{
     background-color:yellow;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/26382/

Comment: You need to change the text to clicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant of @user3249448's ans. It might be what you are looking for

Look at [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71rqq1o1/7/)

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.row = -1;
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.realName=[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"},{"id":3,"name":"c"},{"id":4,"name":"D"},{"id":5,"name":"E"},{"id":6,"name":"F"}];

    $scope.colorRow = function(index){
        $scope.row = index;
    }    

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!

    <div ng-init="item.isyellow = false" ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-class="{yellow : $index == row}"  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-click="colorRow($index)"  style="cursor:pointer"  >
        <span ng-show="$index != row ">{{item.id}}
        {{item.name}}</span>
        <span ng-show="$index == row"> : Cliked</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, but how I could apply your sample on this: http://jsfiddle.net/71rqq1o1/10/ , doing the same but in the field email? so when i click in the email change to yellow and change the text to clicked? can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can check this http://jsfiddle.net/71rqq1o1/

Modify your CSS class

```
.yellow{
     background-color:yellow;
     color:green;
}
```

and

HTML to

```
<div ng-init="item.isyellow = false" ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-class="{yellow : $index == row}"  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-click="colorRow($index)"  style="cursor:pointer"  >
        {{item.id}}
        {{item.name}} <span ng-show="$index == row"> : Cliked</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need remove the old text and include the new one, so per example: remove 1A per Clicked etc.., understand? thank you.

Comment: Ok and what text you want to replace with old text? means "1A" to "Removed 1A"

Comment: remove 1A and insert : clicked, like remove the text from the .js and insert clicked, but puting the text back after click in another DIV

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of rewriting the entire thing using **directives** instead, because I believe your use-case was begging for it :)

---

**Please note:**
What follows seems complicated but it's actually terribly simple to use. Just drop the JS code for the directives in your Angular module and you're good to go.
You don't even need to read it (although it wouldn't hurt) or replace anything, it's ready to use -- and re-use for many similar cases.

---

I created 2 directives that work together:

1. A base element: `clickable-element`, which will know about its `clicked` state.
2. And a container: `clickable-container` that will be a wrapper around a collection of "clickable" elements

### The `clickable-container`

The `clickable-container` will manage the state of all its children `clickable-elements`. Clicking on one on them toggles it on and all the others off.

### The `clickable-element`

For your simple use-case, the `clickable-element`s have only two simple features:

1. They inject a `boolean` value `$clicked` in their scope
2. They have a `clicked` class added/removed depending on their clicked state.

### Example

Your code would now simply look like this:

```
<clickable-container>
  <clickable-element ng-repeat="elem in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']">
    <div ng-if="$clicked">clicked!</div>
    <div ng-if="!$clicked">{{elem}}</div>
  </clickable-element>
</clickable-container>
```

... convenient, isn't it?

### Moreover

1. Using this approach, you can manage several distinct collections of `clickable-element`s with separate `clickable-container`s.
2. The styling and the content are entirely handled by your stylesheet and your HTML code respectively.

### Demonstration

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('clickableContainer', [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: [
          function() {
            const elements = [];

            this.newElement = function() {
              var element = {
                id: elements.length,
                clicked: false
              };

              return elements.push(element), element;
            };

            this.toggle = function(element) {
              elements.forEach(function(e) {
                e.clicked = e.id === element.id;
              });
            };
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('clickableElement', [
    function() {
      return {
        require: '^^clickableContainer',
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-click="_toggle()" ng-class="{clicked: $clicked}" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, clickableContainerCtrl) {
          scope._toggle = clickableContainerCtrl.toggle.bind(clickableContainerCtrl, scope._state = clickableContainerCtrl.newElement());
          scope.$watch('_state.clicked', function(clicked) {
            scope.$clicked = clicked;
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]).name;
```

```css
clickable-element {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[clickable-container] [clickable-element]:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div clickable-container>
    <div clickable-element ng-repeat="elem in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']">
      <div ng-if="$clicked">clicked!</div>
      <div ng-if="!$clicked">{{elem}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```